# How to move a delta ASDA-B2 motor to position x and y?

Tags: java, robotics, servo

I want to write a method which gets two number, `x` and `y` and move the servo to the correct position. `x` and `y` are the position of an object in an image which I extracted before. I have no idea how to move the servo in java. I skimmed the [manual](http://www.acontrol.com.pl/uploads/pdf/instrukcje/ASDA-B2-user-guide.pdf) and it seems there is nothing related to my issue. The servo should point to the position of the object. Mapping the position `x` and `y` to the suitable number for servo movement can be done after finding the way to move the servo.In addition, the servo is placed in the position N and M/2 of an NxM image and should point to the position of the object.
**I use a PC or Laptop to communicate with servo (maybe USB or COM port)**

I use Java 9 and maven.

here is the simplified version of my problem:

```
public void servoInitialization(){
     //initializeation
}
public void servoMove (int x, int y){

    //computation to map the `x` and `y` to correct number for moving the  servo
    //move the servo to the position
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure this will help you though. Please check the protocol being used for your ASDA-B2 is this one. If it is, you can start playing around with it by sending bits to RS232 port(by using the protocol specification). https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1286287/Delta-Asd-B2-0121-B.html?page=253#manual For Cartesian to polar coordinate conversion, [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7dYz.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7dYz.jpg)

Comment: For calculating the angle, have a look at the [atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Comment: Thank you. I'll work on it. I found this in [github](https://github.com/ftctechnh/ftc_app/wiki/Controlling-a-Servo-(OnBot-Java))

Comment: Oh, looking cool. But http://www.revrobotics.com/rev-31-1153/  you need to purchase their product for it. If I were you, I would just buy the Audrino which has more online resources than this.

Comment: Thank you, `Audrino` is an awesome suggestion. Can `Audrino` be used to read IP camera using opencv, and run my java program?

Comment: well my search https://github.com/shibshib/ThermalView .  Say hello to OpenCV for me :D